# Really Simple Php Form To Save To A Text File

Tags: php, forms

I found a code here for saving a form to a text file. The problem is that it doesn't save the form to `/tmp/mydata.txt`. It says "xxx bytes written" but when I open the txt file I can't see the values I submitted.

Also what should I do to save the txt filenames dynamically like `datesubmitted.txt` for example.

```
<form action="myprocessingscript.php" method="POST">
<input name="field1" type="text" />
<input name="field2" type="text" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
    $data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('/tmp/mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
```

Comment: i am really noob sorry should i add it before the file_put_contents ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code should work for you:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
    $data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";
    $filename = date('YmdHis').".txt";
    $ret = file_put_contents($filename, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
?>
```

You can create file dynamically and check if its exist just write your content or create new.

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSSSSSS=)))). You are greatttttttt thanks a lot my friend.

Comment: Glad to help you. you should use "\r\n" for new line instead of "\n".